# How to Write connection string in asp.net core Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to create the database connection in my .net core Web API how to I write the connection string. In App setting file how to I write the connection string.

Comment: [How to add a connection string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got my answer

```
"Data": {
  "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-ConfigurationSample-ad90971f-6620-4bc1-ad28-650c59478cc1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

here is link 
http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/01/json-config-in-aspnetcoremvc/

Answer (score 7):

WEB API has a configuration file 'appsettings.json', in this file you can put all the configuration or variables that you need, for example would be like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  //->
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=dbname;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;Password=mypass"
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "SecretKey": "myjwtpass"
  },
  "EmailConfiguration": {
    "SmtpServer": "mysmtpserver",
    "SmtpPort": 2525,
    "SmtpUsername": "myusername",
    "SmtpPassword": "mypassword"
  }
  //<-
}
```

To obtain the values of the configuration we show the following example:

In the constructor get this from injection:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public MyClassName(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

In some method:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
     var jwtPass = Configuration["Jwt:SecretKey"];
     var connStr = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

--I use Solution
string condb = "";
public readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
 public ValuesController(IConfiguration configuration) 
{  
_configuration = configuration;
condb = _configuration[ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection];

}

Comment: Please also explain what the posted code does and why it will resolve the question.